# In WPF, how do I override style set by the template at the instance level?

Tags: wpf

So I have a custom template for scrollbar.  It work great, but I would like to override the corner rounding value.  On the template, it is set like this:

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalScroll" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Grid>
            <Border Grid.RowSpan="3" CornerRadius="3" BorderBrush="DarkBlue" BorderThickness="1" Opacity=".6"></Border>
```

I am creating my instance like this:

```
    <ScrollViewer Padding="0,0,0,0">
        <TextBlock  Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Name="textBlock1" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </ScrollViewer>
```

How do I change the CornerRadius to 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's any easy way to do this, since there is no template inheritance in WPF.  You would either have to copy your entire template and modify it for this particular instance, or set the template in *Styles*

Answer (score 0):

Use an Attached DependencyProperty. The Attached DependencyProperty allows you to store information and against a DependencyObject.

So, create an Attached DependencyProperty, in the following case, against the MainWindow.

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CornerRadiusProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CornerRadius", typeof(int), typeof(MainWindow));

    public static void SetCornerRadius(DependencyObject element, int value)
    {
        element.SetValue(CornerRadiusProperty, value);
    }

    public static int GetCornerRadius(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (int) element.GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty);
    }
```

Then in the Xaml, on the ScrollViewer assign the value

```
<ScrollViewer Padding="0,0,0,0" this:MainWindow.CornerRadius="20" ... >
```

and in the template, reference the Attached DependencyProperty using a TemplatedParent binding.

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ScrollViewerTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
        <Grid>
            <Border Grid.RowSpan="3" CornerRadius="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=(this:MainWindow.CornerRadius)}" BorderBrush="DarkBlue" BorderThickness="1" Opacity=".6">
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In case its only property you interested to set from outside, you can store value in `Tag` and do `TemplateBinding` with Tag.

```
<Border CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding Tag}"/>
```

and in instance ScrollViewer:

```
<ScrollViewer Tag="6"/>
```

However, if there are more properties you want to set from outside, either *subclass ScrollViewer and create your custom DP's* or you can also go with [attached properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in case not interested in subclassing of ScrollViewer.